# Sqlite Xamarin - Error CS0029 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'OwsX.Models.User' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OwsX.Models.User>'

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, model-view-controller

Hola estoy desarrollando un aplicación con **Xamarin** y quisisera guardar algunos datos en una tabla, pero antes de checar esos datos quisiera saber antes si esa tabla existe y si es el caso , si tiene contenido , para entonces actualizarlo o escribir en la tabla ...

hasta ahora tengo esto

```js
namespace OwsX
{
    class DataAccess : IDisposable
    {

        private SQLiteConnection connection;

        public DataAccess()
        {
            //config buscara la dependecias de IConfig
            var config = DependencyService.Get<IConf>();
            //.db3 es la extención de sqlite
            connection = new SQLiteConnection(config.Platform,
                Path.Combine(config.DbPath, "User.db3"));

            connection.CreateTable<User>();
        }

        public void InsertUser(User user)
        {
            connection.Insert(user);
        }

        public void UpdateUser(User user)
        {
            connection.Update(user);
        }

        public void DeleteUser(User user)
        {
            connection.Delete(user);
        }

        public User GetUser(int id)
        {
            return connection.Table<User>().FirstOrDefault(
                c => c.id == id);
        }

        public List<User> GetUserOnly()
        {
            return connection.Table<User>().ToList();
        }


        //Liberar el recurso
        public void Dispose()
        {
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

quiero usar el metodo **GetUserOnly** para saber que hay dentro y hacer una comparación y dependiende de su contenido mandarme para un lado para el otro. 
algo así ...

```js
try {
  using(var user_datos = new DataAccess()) {
    var localdata = user_datos.GetUserOnly();
    if(localdata != null){
  
      /*
      leer datos y devolver en  otra vista con los datos
      */
    }else{
      /*funcion para implementar datos*/
    }
  }
} catch (Exception) {

  DisplayAlert("fack", "sqlite", "ok");
}
```

El compilador no me manda un error pero si la lista de error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguien podría ayudarme? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la exception tendrias que cambiar de

```
    public List<User> GetUserOnly()
    {
        return connection.Table<User>().ToList();
    }
```

A

```
    public User GetUserOnly()
    {
        return connection.Table<User>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

> Porque segun el error estas tratando de asignar una lista a una variable que solo espera un objeto.